# How can we rewrite this optimization problem in standard form?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, discrete-optimization

Consider the following problem
$$
\begin{array}{crl}
&\underset{y}{\max} & f(y)\\
s.t. & y_{1}A_{1}+y_{2}A_{2}+S_{1}&=C_{1},\\
 & y_{3}A_{3}+y_{2}A_{4}+y_{5}A_{5}+S_{2}&=C_{2},\\
 & y_{3}A_{6}+y_{4}A_{7}+S_{3}&=C_{3},\\
 & S_{1},S_{2},S_{3}\succeq0,
\end{array}
$$
where $y_{i}$ are scalar variables and the matrices $A_{i}$ are symmetric real. How can we rewrite this optimzation
problem in the following form 
$$
\begin{array}{crl}
&\underset{y}{\max} & f(y)\\
s.t. & \sum_{i=1}^{m}y_{i}A_{i}+S&=C,\\
  &S&\succeq0,
\end{array}
$$
where $x_{i}$ are scalar variables and the matrices $B_{i}$ are symmetric real. please? Thanks.

Comment: Define $T$ as a block diagonal matrix with $S_i$ on the diagonal. Same for $B_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rewrite the problem as
$$
\begin{array}{crl}
&\underset{y}{\max} & f(y)\\
s.t. & y_{1}A_{1}+y_{2}A_{2}+S_{1}&=C_{1},\\
 & y_{3}A_{3}+y_{2}A_{4}+y_{4}A_{5}+S_{2}&=C_{2},\\
 & y_{3}A_{6}+y_{4}A_{7}+S_{3}&=C_{3},\\
 & S_{1},S_{2},S_{3}\succeq0,
\end{array}
$$
changing the variable $y_5$ by the variable $y_4$. The three equations that define equality constraints can be written in a single equation using block-partitioned matrices.
$$
{
\begin{array}{rl}
\underset{y}{\max} & f(y)\\
y_1
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
A_1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0
\end{array}\right]
+
y_2
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
A_2&0&0\\0&A_4&0\\0&0&0
\end{array}\right]
+
y_3
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0\\0&A_3&0\\0&0&A_6
\end{array}\right]
+
y_4
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0\\0&A_5&0\\0&0&A_7
\end{array}\right]
+
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
S_1&0&0\\0&S_2&0\\0&0&S_3
\end{array}\right]
&=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
C_1&0&0\\0&C_2&0\\0&0&C_3
\end{array}\right]
\\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
S_1&0&0\\0&S_2&0\\0&0&S_3
\end{array}\right]
&\succeq  0
\end{array}
}
$$

Comment: Thank you MathOverview. You are right, I am using this method to solve the following problem but the obtained matrices are not symmetric: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860527/how-to-rewrite-this-optimization-problem-in-standard-form      Do you have an opinion on the question of this link please?